# How to note data source in a data JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, database, javascript-objects

I have a few data JSON files similar to [this](https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json) and I want to include a line to note the sources as simple as `//source: Cambodia Department of Injustice` but JSON files should contain only data.

Should should it be done?

Comment: JSON files don't support comments. Maybe you can add the attribution in a footnote on your web page itself?

Comment: You could add an extra property to the file.

Comment: @SimonK that's the issue. You collect a bunch of data into some JSON files. When I look back in a few months, I can't recall where they come from

Comment: @Barmar that's a way (and only way I see) like `{ "USA": {some data}, "Canada": {some data}, "non-data": {"source": "Cambodia Department of Injustice", "source date": "12-2015", "note": "the data look fake but better than nothing"} }` . But the file will then be more difficult to use and code must explicitly not read the `non-data` key

Comment: Do you use GIT? If so you could add the provider in the commit message and then just check the history of commits on that file?

Comment: @SimonK that's not a portable solution

Comment: Oh right - I thought the note was just for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the data structure slightly, you could add a level for metadata:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "source": "Cambodia Department of Justice",
        "source-date": "2015-12-15",
        "note": "Ha ha made you look"
    },
    "countries": {
        "USA": { some data }
        "Canada": { Some data }
    }
}
```

This is cleaner than use a fake "non-data" country.

Comment: I guess that it the best solution even I personally would prefer a simple comment if possible